# I cannot delete a folder because it has endless folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-management, infinite-loop

It seems some software had a bug and created a endless path of folders like:

folderA/folderB/folderC/folderA/folderB/folderC...

[image: screenshot]

I cannot delete it because Windows says that the path is too long.

How can I delete them?

Comment: Actually the solution that worked for me was this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/667062/removing-an-apparently-infinitely-recursive-folder/667198#667198

Comment: But as I'm in Windows 7, the code changed to: `RecursiveDelete(new DirectoryInfo("D:\\folderX\\folderY\\folder_to_delete"));`